# tycho: missing org.eclipse.tycho.core.TychoProject

Tags: tycho

I try to run tycho in ubuntu, but I face this error.
 Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.14.1:build-qualifier (default-build-qualifier) on project tychodemo.bundle: Execution default-build-qualifier of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.14.1:build-qualifier failed: Unable to load the mojo 'build-qualifier' in the plugin 'org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.14.1'. A required class is missing: org.eclipse.tycho.core.TychoProject

I guess it's related to my framework, because I do  the same in another computer and tycho run succesfully.Can you detect my problem?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class loader errors for Tycho classes are typically caused by mixing multiple Tycho versions in the same reactor. Being a build build extension, there must only be one version of Tycho active at a time.

To do this, check that your reactor uses the same version for the Tycho build extension and the Tycho plug-ins, e.g. by using the variable `${tycho-version}` as version and defining that version in your parent POM:

```
<properties>
   <tycho-version>0.14.1</tycho-version>
</properties>
```

Also make sure that all your modules reference the same parent POM, and not an older version of the POM.